# Quake 4 libGL error on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 16.04, fglrx, amd-graphics

```
sh quake4
```

...

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Any ideas what to do? :(

video adapter: RADEON HD 5770

P.S.: Installing fglrx driver breaking xorg (low graphics mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm libstdc++.so.6
rm libgcc_s.so.1
```

at the game folder